# Redirect to new page after form submition

Tags: javascript

How do i redirect to another page after form submition. This is my code:

```
    form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        
        console.log("sasadas")

        mal = {
            "omkrets": form.omkrets.value,
            "areal": form.areal.value,
            "hoyde": form.hoyde.value,
        }

        document.cookie = 'mal=' + JSON.stringify(mal) + ";domain=;path=/";
        window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/kategori/";
    })
```

I've tried window.location.href but doesn't work. Any ideas? I've searched around but didn't find a definitive answer.

Comment: Try replacing `e.preventDefault;` with `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: And also let me know if you have anything logging on the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace,

`e.preventDefault;`

by

`e.preventDefault();`